# Применение функций, предлагающих обратное/стороннее действие, как опцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs, классы

Вдохновленный методом `subscribe/unsubscribe` в `Redux`, я подумал, а почему бы, не попробовать прописывать методы, выполняющие свою инструкцию, к примеру в Классе, но возвращающие, как опцию, дополнительную метод, скажем для обратного действия... или еще для чего-нибудь...

```
class Some {
        constructor(data={}) {
            this._data = data;
        }
        initSome(data) { //getter/setter method
            if (data) {
                if (typeof data === 'object' && Object.keys(data).length) {
                    const prevData = {...this._data};
                    this._data = {...data};
                    return () => this._data = {...prevData}; //даем обратное действие
                } else {
                    console.error('given argument is not object or empty');
                }

            } else {
                return this._data;
            }
        }
    }

    const sample = new Some({one: 1, two: 2});
    const undo = sample.initSome({one: 10, two: 20});  //undo получает функцию
    console.log(sample.initSome());  //{one: 10, two: 20}
    undo(); //undo выполняет возврат к прежнему состоянию
    console.log(sample.initSome()); {one: 1, two: 2}
```

Если разойтись, то можно пушить эти переменные в массив и использовать как массив возврата состояний... Экземпляр, кстати, тоже мог бы их собирать в своем свойстве...
Насколько это будет правильной практикой? Я все понимаю про single responsibility, но тут, вроде, метод ничего дополнительно не выполняет: просто возвращает, как опцию, метод обратного действия.... или какого-либо еще действия...

Не бейте сильно по ушам, пожалуйста... :))

Comment: Какой в этом смысл? о_О

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, сначала появилась идея водостойкого клея, а потом уже появилась идея водостойкой наждачной бумаги...
Тут идея в выполнении инструкции с возвратом инструкции обратного действия...

Comment: Идея понятна. Смысл в чем? Где и как вы это будете применять? Мне кажется, такие вещи очень специфичны.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, ну скажем, можно, выполняя действия, иметь в конечном счете массив обратных состояний (историю состояний)... и выбирать при необходимости нужный state...
даже не знаю :)
посчитал это интересным...

Comment: Наверное, в 80% случаев в state хранятся данные, которые отражают состояние модели\даных в БД. В таком случае, надо уметь откатывать и данные в БД.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, согласен, но БД, имхо, должна отражать уверенные финальные состояния, а не предварительную черновую работу с данными. Возможно, это может быть полезно на Клиенте для работы с черновыми состояниями... 
в любом случае - это ведь идея-заготовка... возможно может иметь у кого-нибудь продолжение... с уважением...